# Why can't I create a simple SQL Agent Job or find correct syntax?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssas

This works perfectly in a SSMS 2008 query window:

```
use [HSS Maintenance]

exec HSS_Guest.[olap storedprocedure]
exec HSS_Guest.[MAKE OLAP_CUBE]
```

But when I build an Agent Job and then test by using "Start Job at Step..." it always fails.

I have tried Operating System (CmdExec) "Type" as well as T-SQL and even SSAS I believe.

Am I having a Syntax issue or not using the correct "Type"?

Using full rights on an Enterprise edition & Server 2008.

I have Googled this to death and do not believe that I can't just build this simply via the GUI.

Please show me how dumb I am!

Note - I have tried to generate the Script from the Job window and get an error that "There is no Action to be Scripted"

Comment: Needs to be a TSQL Job Step. Try getting rid of the `use HSS Maintenance` and setting the right database context in your SQL Agent job (there is a dropdown list if I remember correctly)? What error do you get?

Comment: Great today it seems to be working now, I had tried many different combinations previously.

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate response!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the SQL Server Agent job that contains the step that has the SQL code you posted. Remove the "use [HSS Maintenance]" line and instead use the drop down menu on the step to choose this database.